# React - Is there a way to get the value without messing up the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-context

I have a situation where I want to pass a value using `Context + Hooks` to another component, but the problem is that I do not need to import the component inside the provider to get the value in more understandable language, then imagine that I have two `SideBarBlurChange` components and `SideBar` inside the `SideBarBlurChange` component, I have a value in my case, this is a simple number that I want to pass inside the `SideBar` component, but the problem is that I don't want to import the `SideBar` inside the `SideBarBlurChange` component to get this value, because my entire project will collapse and get something like

[image]

As you can see, when importing the `SideBar` component inside the `SideBarBlurChange` component, the page collapsed, my question, how did you understand this, can I get a value called values inside the `SideBar` component, I'll lay out my code forever

**SideBarBlurChange.jsx**

```
export const BlurContext = createContext({
    BlurChangeValue: [],
});

export default function SideBarBlurChange(props) {

    const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));
    const [values, SetValues] = useState(ls ? [ls] : [20]);

    const SaveChanges = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('values', values);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <BlurContext.Provider value={{ BlurChangeValue: values }}>
                // jsx
            </BlurContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

**SideBar.jsx**

```
export default function SideBar(props) {

    const {SideBarValue, SideBarWallpaperValue} = React.useContext(CounterContext);

    const [SideBarTheme] = SideBarValue;
    const [SideBarBackground] = SideBarWallpaperValue;

    const {BlurChangeValue} = {...React.useContext(BlurContext)}
    const [count] = BlurChangeValue;

    return (
        <div className={"headline_sidebar_wrapper"}>
            <article className={`${Blur.glass} ${Blur.up}`}>
                <nav id="sidebar" className="sidebar-wrapper modal">
                    <p>{count}</p>
                    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${SideBarBackground})`}}>
                        <div style={{background: SideBarTheme, backdropFilter: "blur(60px)"}}
                             className={`${Blur.SideBar_Page_Content} ${Blur.SideBarContainer}`}>
                            <SideBarWrapper {...props} />
                            <div className="sidebar-menu">
                                <SideBarMenu path={props.match.path}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </article>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

I would also like to provide you with a picture, please note that inside the provider I get the value `73` but in the `SideBar` component I get `undefined` I am almost sure that this is due to the fact that I do not import anything inside the `SideBarBlurChange` question how to get or is there a way to get the value without component corruption? Thank you earlier for paying attention to my long question

Comment: Why are you doing `const {BlurChangeValue} = {...React.useContext(BlurContext)}` as opposed to just `const { BlurChangeValue } = React.useContext(BlurContext)`

Comment: So what? this approach does not work

Comment: I was asking because I didn't understand the purpose, and also thought it could mess something up maybe, but if not, ok.

Otherwise, it might be helpful is you showed where/how `Sidebar` is rendered within `SideBarBlurChange`'s context provider.

Comment: @Synchro `my question, how did you understand this,` Excellent question, I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifting State Up or how to get the value in another component without import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074314/lifting-state-up-or-how-to-get-the-value-in-another-component-without-import)