# Lifting State Up or how to get the value in another component without import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-props

I have a lot of components I need to get a value called "`values`" from the `SideBarBlurChange` component to the `SideBar` component. I drew a diagram of my components so you can navigate easier

[image]

I read articles and how I understood there are two main options, the first is "**Lifting State Up**" and the second is "**Redux**" or "**Context**". I tried to apply these approaches but I failed.

The main problem is that inside the `SideBarBlurChange` component, I cannot import anything, since my entire project is collapsing. In addition to all this, I will leave a link to this project in the github if you want to see [GitHub Project](https://github.com/SuroZaqaryan/Portfolio_v_1.0.git)

Now I want to explain my problem in more detail.

[image]

Please pay attention to the changing **number** I showed with the mouse this **number** and there is a value with the name "`values`". I need to apply this value to the SideBar component to adjust the blur of the Sidebar.

And finally, before I demonstrate my code, I imported the SideBar inside the SideBarBlurChange, took out a value called "values" and applied it to the SideBar component like this `<div style = {{backdropFilter: blur(${props.values}px)}}...`

[image]

Now look my project has collapsed, I mean that there is a catastrophe for my components, but I got "`values`" and everything works for me.

Now I think that the problem is understandable, in order not to confuse you, I will show you three `SideBar` components, `SideBarBlurChange` and `DraggableDialog` where I imported `SideBarBlurChange`, + delete all personal code and show only the most important thing, but if you need to look at all the other components, I will remind you that I left a link to project in github, or as a last resort, tell me I will edit my question and show what you need in advance. I want to thank you for taking the time to solve my problem

**SideBar.jsx**

```
export default function SideBar(props) {
    return (
        <div style={{backdropFilter: "blur(60px)"}}>
            // jsx code
        </div>
    );
}
```

**SideBarBlurChange.jsx**

```
const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 100;

export default function SideBarBlurChange(props) {

    const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));
    const [values, SetValues] = useState(ls ? [ls] : [20]);

    const SaveChanges = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('values', values);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Range
                    // code
                />
                <output style={{ marginTop: "30px" }} id="output">
                    {values[0].toFixed(1)}
                </output>

                <button onClick={() => SaveChanges()}>Save</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

**DraggableDialog.jsx**

```
const DraggableDialog = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <SideBarBlurChange {...props}/>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default DraggableDialog;
```

I removed a lot of code from these three components, I left only the most important. Sorry in advance, I don't know English, I wrote it all with the help of translate

Comment: You asked this [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028927/react-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-value-without-messing-up-the-component) so I cloned the repo and had no problem [adding context](https://github.com/SuroZaqaryan/Portfolio_v_1.0/pull/1/files)

Comment: I know that according to the rules of this site there is no need to thank, but I cannot do it :) thank you very much

Comment: No problem, hope you'll get it to work but if you don't just let us know.

Comment: Everything worked fine for me thanks again